# is left join is solution?

Tags: mysql

```
Table1  
F1   F2   F3   F4 
ab1  bc1  de1  5
ab2  bc2  de2  6
ab3  bc3  de3  0

Table2 
F21 F22  F23
5   five  d
6   six   e

Table3 
f31 
ab1
ab2
ab3


 select a.f1 a.f2 b.f22  from Table1 as a Table2 as b Table3 as c 
 where a.f1 = c.f31  and a.f4 = b.f21
```

I am looking for result

ab1  bc1  five

ab2  bc2  sex

ab3  bc3   ""

I dont know how to ask this . But my question is if a.f4 = b.f21 is not matcheed which means

0 is not there in table 3 but still i want to result with empty value .. how to acheive this ?

Comment: use LEFT JOIN. http://hashmysql.org/index.php?title=Introduction_to_Joins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you should use a [LEFT JOIN](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1667). This does require rewriting your query a bit.

> LEFT OUTER JOIN - Based on the two
>   tables specified in the join clause,
>   all data is returned from the left
>   table.  On the right table, the
>   matching data is returned in addition
>   to NULL values where a record exists
>   in the left table, but not in the
>   right table.  Another item to keep in
>   mind is that the LEFT and RIGHT OUTER
>   JOIN logic is opposite of one another.
>   So you can change either the order of
>   the tables in the specific join
>   statement or change the JOIN from left
>   to right or vice versa and get the
>   same results.

```
  SELECT  a.f1 a.f2 b.f22  
  FROM    Table1 as a 
          LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 as b ON a.f4 = b.f21
          LEFT OUTER JOIN Table3 as c ON c.f31 = a.f1
```